# Displaying form submission errors inline

Tags: error, validation

Is there module to improve the errors in Expression engine ? The in build system is pretty cumbersome and without spending time building multiple form validation classes I would like something that does not send you to the error page but shows the errors on the current page.

Comment: What kind of forms would these be? Member login? Member registration? Some 3rd party member addons do inline validation in this case.

Comment: the custom errors.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by the custom errors. Could you give me an example?

Comment: maybe used the wrong terminology http://i.stack.imgur.com/6LJfv.png

Comment: they  might be called message pages http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/message_pages/

Answer (score 1):

The User Message templates are the native behavior of EE, but there are some addons that you can use to work around them.

A 3rd party addon like Free Member https://github.com/expressodev/freemember can display errors like required fields inline to avoid EE's user message templates.

Beyond that if there is a specific message you are trying to avoid from another form submission there's likely an addon that can do it.

You may also want to check out this the Custom System Messages Addon http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages.